# How to increase the render resolution in God of War pc?

Tags: pc, god-of-war

My laptop has 16GB RAM and a Geforce GTX 1060 6GB. The render resolution option is disabled in the game settings. Is it possible to increase it on my laptop, or is GTX incapable of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

God of War has two explicit resolution settings, *Output Resolution* and *Render Resolution*:

[image]

If you [turn off DLSS](https://www.reddit.com/r/blackopscoldwar/comments/jtukdu/render_resolution_locked/), you can adjust these resolutions. But seeing that your GPU doesn't support DLSS, you might have to [turn off/adjust the AMD FSR 2.0 setting](https://www.reddit.com/r/GodofWar/comments/wkbg3b/why_does_god_of_war_pc_look_so_fuzzy_and_low/) (under the header *Resolution Scaling*) to unlock these settings.

All the settings mentioned pose a convoluted way to get the best out of the resolution you're actually seeing in-game. I assume this is because it's ported from the PlayStation.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working